# Comparing response properties with data with Soapui and groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to compare an array of codes with the codes I get from a response in Soapui.
I was able to add an array to a groovy script containing the entries I had in an excel so basically e.g

```
def MAX_SIZE = 31
def myArray = new Object[MAX_SIZE]

// Code array
myArray[0] = "EU1234qSP"
myArray[1] = "ES1234qSPwe"
myArray[2] = "EF1234qSPde"
myArray[3] = "EW1234qSPpt"
```

Then I have expanded the properties Xpath from the web service response that returns the code from the data base. e.g:

```
def OfferCode1 = context.expand( '${QuerySubsPlanList - Request 1#Response#declare namespace ns=\'http://com.ztesoft.zsmart/xsd\'; //ns:QuerySubsPlanListResponse[1]/SubsPlanDtoList[1]/SubsPlanDto[1]/SubsPlanCode[1]}' )
def OfferCode2 = context.expand( '${QuerySubsPlanList - Request 1#Response#declare namespace ns=\'http://com.ztesoft.zsmart/xsd\'; //ns:QuerySubsPlanListResponse[1]/SubsPlanDtoList[1]/SubsPlanDto[2]/SubsPlanCode[1]}' )
def OfferCode3 = context.expand( '${QuerySubsPlanList - Request 1#Response#declare namespace ns=\'http://com.ztesoft.zsmart/xsd\'; //ns:QuerySubsPlanListResponse[1]/SubsPlanDtoList[1]/SubsPlanDto[3]/SubsPlanCode[1]}' )
def OfferCode4 = context.expand( '${QuerySubsPlanList - Request 1#Response#declare namespace ns=\'http://com.ztesoft.zsmart/xsd\'; //ns:QuerySubsPlanListResponse[1]/SubsPlanDtoList[1]/SubsPlanDto[4]/SubsPlanCode[1]}' )
```

What is the best approach to compare them and print in the log that there is a match or fail?
A loop? maybe something like

```
for (item in myArray ) {



    for (offerCode in offerCodesArray) {}


    if (item == offerCode) {
        store the finding
        go to next item in myArray
    }
    }
}


}
```

how would I enter the expanded properties in to an array then? never did that before
still a beginner at this, can anyone help?

Cheers
Adi

Update: the Changes in the DB are more frequent than I thought, so I do need the nodes count to work.
The structure of the response is as follows

```
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:QuerySubsPlanListResponse xmlns:ns="http://com.ztesoft.zsmart/xsd">
         <SubsPlanDtoList>
            <SubsPlanDto>
               <SubsPlanCode>TEST1</SubsPlanCode>
               <ServType>M</ServType>
               <CustTypeList>B2B</CustTypeList>
               <Price>0.0000</Price>
            </SubsPlanDto>
            <SubsPlanDto>
               <SubsPlanCode>TEST2 </SubsPlanCode>
               <ServType>M</ServType>
               <CustTypeList>B2C|B2B</CustTypeList>
               <Price>0.0000</Price>
            </SubsPlanDto>
```

can anyone tell me how to count the nodes? the last suggestion above did not work. Thanks

Comment: Are there only four, or are there more? Where do the expected values come from? Are they fixed or do they change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`java.util.Collection`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html) from groovy-jdk instead of an array, and then you can use `intersect`, `plus` (for union) etc. to work with this collections an get the match and fails. I give you a source sample:

```
def myCollection = ["1","2","3","4"]
def myCollection2 = ["1","a","3","d"]
def matches = myCollection.intersect(myCollection2)
def fails = myCollection.plus(myCollection2)
fails.removeAll(matches)

log.info matches // --> [1,3] matches
log.info fails // --> [2,4,a,d] not match
```

With this code you can print the matches and fails, and also you have a collection with your matches like you want.

About enter expanded properties in a collection: If you want to loop thought `<SubsPlanDto>` in your response as your answer suggests, you can count the number of instances of this element with an XPath and then make a loop adding each element to the collection (Please note that you can use a wildcard `*` as namespace to keep XPath simplier), see the code below:

```
def numElements = context.expand( '${QuerySubsPlanList - Request 1#Response#//count(*:QuerySubsPlanListResponse[1]/SubsPlanDtoList[1]/SubsPlanDto)}')
def collection2 = [];
for ( i in 1..numElements.toInteger()) {
    collection2.add(context.expand( '${QuerySubsPlanList - Request 1#Response#//*:QuerySubsPlanListResponse[1]/SubsPlanDtoList[1]/SubsPlanDto['+ i + ']/SubsPlanCode[1]}'))
}
```

Finally you can do it all together:

```
// you collection definition...
def collection = ["1","2","3","4"]

// get num repetitions of <SubsPlanDto> with Xpath count
def numElements = context.expand( '${QuerySubsPlanList - Request 1#Response#//count(*:QuerySubsPlanListResponse[1]/SubsPlanDtoList[1]/SubsPlanDto)}')
def collection2 = [];
// iterate and add the values to a collection
for ( i in 1..numElements.toInteger()) {
    collection2.add(context.expand( '${QuerySubsPlanList - Request 1#Response#//*:QuerySubsPlanListResponse[1]/SubsPlanDtoList[1]/SubsPlanDto['+ i + ']/SubsPlanCode[1]}'))
}

// get the matches and differences
def matches = collection.intersect(collection2)
def fails = collection.plus(collection2)
fails.removeAll(matches)

log.info matches
log.info fails
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks a lot! I learned some new stuff! got it working, though the nodes count does not work, I've added the number manually and the script is working. Ill try googling for getting the nodes count.

Comment: if the answer helps you, remember to accept it :). Beside the XPath function count() must works... may be is another problem? Can you share your error with count()?

Comment: How do I accept it? (first time here). There is no error but only one code is added to the collection. when I define Numelements as 45 then it works.

Comment: To accept an answer check the tick beside it (for more info you can read the about page http://stackoverflow.com/tour :) ). About the count the behavior you describe it's strange. The `count(*:QuerySubsPlanListResponse[1]/SubsPlanDtoList[1]/SubsPlanDto)` doesn't work, however then you can iterate over this nodes `//*:QuerySubsPlanListResponse[1]/SubsPlanDtoList[1]/SubsPlanDto['+ i + ']/SubsPlanCode[1]}`? Can you post your response and the groovy code somewhere in order to check it? What SOAPUI version are you using?

Comment: Ok accepted it I think :). Sorry but I can't post the actual code and response with the real codes. For now it works for me like this but ill keep looking for ways to do that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am opening this question again, since the counting of the nodes becomes an important thing. There are frequent changes in the data base and I need it more than I thought.

Comment: I've added the response

Comment: I think it would be better to open a new question and add the xsd of your response and a sample of it, however you can try in groovy script with: `def numElements = context.expand( '${YOUR SOAPUI REQUEST NAME#Response#//count(*:QuerySubsPlanListResponse/*:SubsPlanDtoList/*:SubsPlanDto)}')`, this must works.